# Will debugging change the behavior of a multi-thread C++ program?

Tags: c++, multithreading, debugging, visual-studio-2008, asynchronous

I am working on a multi-threaded C++ program which deals with a lot of synchronization issues. I am using Visual Studio 2008.

The run-time behavior of my program (the order in which statements are executed across threads) seems to change when I debug it using breakpoints. Can this be explained? What is the concept at play here? I would expect the order of execution to remain the same.

Second question - if Thread1 is blocked by, say, a wait function call. Thread2 has statements waiting to be executed, in ready state. Is there any situation where the program will wait for Thread1 to proceed rather than giving execution to Thread2? I have removed all dependencies between the two thread and ensured that Thread2 is not waiting for any resource.

Appreciate the responses.

Comment: Definitely. The behavior of a multi-theaded program can change even if you don't change anything - let alone with a debugger.

Comment: Simply do not make any assumptions with threading and the order of statements executed between threads. Sooner or later all different permutations will happen if there is no proper synchronisation. Also when debugging the code will not use optimizations.

Comment: You just can't predict in which order two threads will execute, they might (or will) execute the statements in different order between two different runs of the same program without changing anything.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[This article on multithreaded debugging techniques](http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/multithreaded-debugging-techniques/199200938) makes a few good summary points on the topic:

> Multithreaded bugs may not surface when running under the debugger. Multithreading bugs are very sensitive to the timing of events in an application. Running the application under the debugger changes the timing, and as a result, may mask problems. When your application fails in a test or worse, the customer environment, but runs reliably under the debugger, it is almost certainly a timing issue in the code.

...and more to your specific latter question, it's important to understand that--in the majority case--the operating system is free to interrupt the execution of any of your threads whenever it pleases, even ones that are "ready" to execute.

Comment: even switching compiler options may change the behavior as it can change the timings as well. Consider adding a good amount of logging (but as it changes timing, this may cause problems in finding the bug as well - but a good logging is always worth it).

Answer (score 2):

Remember: There's no way to normally debug a multithreaded application, as in debugging it "until it works".

You need to have a way of somehow proving to yourself that there won't be deadlocks, and that all the data accesses are serialized where they need to be. This is quite hard to do, and even experienced developers may miss certain cases.

Thus it's very important that you design your multithreaded application so that the design guarantees certain properties (for example -- freedom from deadlocks). Notice that nowhere in the previous sentence is debugging ever mentioned. It needs to work by design, not by error hunting.

There are two core issues:

1. Serialization of access to data structures.
2. Deadlock.

The event driven or CSP approach that I talk about below automatically takes care of #1. The issue of deadlock is not trivial, and is still an active research topic. Namely, the ways of proving lack of deadlock (and also designing for it!).

One example of a design that makes it easy-ier to check for and formally prove certain properties, like freedom from deadlocks, is [communicating sequential processes (CSP)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Communicating_sequential_processes).

The CSP approach is available in most application development frameworks, and can be implemented as a shared-nothing event driven system. The core features are:

- The threads communicate by sending events (messages) between each other.
- The data structures are never directly shared between threads, events own the data instead.
- The only synchronization is done to sequentially access the event queue when an event is posted.

This by itself ensures freedom from deadlocks as long as higher-level abstractions are not using event passing to re-implement deadlock-prone abstractions. For example, the deadlock in dining philosophers problem can be obtained even with event passing, but you are now explicitly passing information about resources via events (messages). Thus the issue is at least made explicit and you are forced to think about it. The problem is not swept under the rug so to speak.

[Formal techniques](http://wotug.org/parallel/theory/formal/csp/Deadlock/) of *proving* that no deadlock/livelock can occur can be easier to apply to event-passing production code that implements CSP. The event-accepting code can provide runtime introspection that allows extraction of the set of accepted events for each state, as well as the set of states (internally it'd be a state machine). This information can be often sufficient to either prove no possibility of a deadlock, or can enumerate a small set of deadlock scenarios that can then be dealt with otherwise. The CSP formalism can't usually capture full semantics of the software, after all, so the semantics itself may be used to further show that a deadlock doesn't happen, or that it is otherwise dealt with.